# Bouncing and moving in Diplomacy

Tags: diplomacy

Specifically, if an invading fleet wanted to move from Naples to Rome, but the move was blocked by another fleet trying to move into Rome from the Tyrrhenian Sea, could a third player with a fleet in the Ionian Sea move into Naples, driving the invading fleet trying to move from Naples to Rome into the sea? 
Or is that just wishful thinking?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've removed a sentence from your question that I think would be better omitted or as a comment underneath (like this one). I've also removed similar content from the title - you don't need to apologize or justify not knowing the answers already; that's why we have a Q&A site :)

Answer (score 3):

All the moves will fail; everything will end up where it started. From the [rules](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/ah/diplomacy_rules.pdf), p9:

> One unit not moving can stop a unit or series of units
>    from moving. If a unit is ordered to hold, or is prevented
>    from moving, and other units are ordered into its province,
>    those other units can’t move. (It’s like a traffic backup!)

Comment: It could be added that if the fleet from Ionian sea had support into Naples then that move would suceed and the fleet in Naples would have to retreat.  (I can not remember if it would be allowed to retreat to Rome)